# Faster Method to Deleting all Rows except header in a Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a query,
I am trying to delete all the rows in my table except for my header.

This is the code that I am using.

```
Sub Trial 
    Dim ws as Worksheet, tName as ListObject, lastRow as Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tName = ws.ListObject("Table3")
    
    With tName.Range
                    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
                    lastRow = tName.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                    
                    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
                        Selection.ListObject.ListRows(i).Delete
                    Next i
    End With

     
End Sub
```

**This works, but it takes about 6 minutes to delete 4000 Rows. is there a faster way about it???**

Things I have tried. (pls note: there is no other table in the sheet)

1st

```
    ws.Range("A2")
    ws.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ws.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete
```

Didnt work, threw the following error `this won't work because it would move cells in a table`

2nd was

```
   ws.Range("A2").currentRegion.offset(1).select
   Selection.Delete
```

This also didnt work, threw the following error `this won't work because it would move cells in a table`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored in the `DataBodyRange`.  Rather than count the rows in that range and delete one by one, just check if anything exists in there and delete it all.

```
Public Sub DeleteTableContents()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    If Not lo.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        lo.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

To add data to the table you can use something like the code below:

```
Public Sub PopulateTable()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim MyNewRow As ListRow
    
    With lo
        'Add a new row to the DataBodyRange and populate by table column number.
        Set MyNewRow = .ListRows.Add
        MyNewRow.Range(1) = "A"
        MyNewRow.Range(2) = "B"
        
        '--OR--
        
        'Populate by table column name.
        MyNewRow.Range(.ListColumns("ColumnName").Index) = "B"
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd like to add, if you intend to write data back you might find that the reference to `DataBodyRange` is missing after you deleted it - In that case, writing something into the cell 1 below the `HeaderRowRange` (`.HeaderRowRange.Cells(2,1).Value="x"`) - and deleting it afterwards - leaves the table with a single empty line, and intact reference.

Comment: @FranzReischl You can use `lo.ListRows.Add` to add a new row to the table.  I'll update my answer with an example of adding data back.